# Location of the parse attribute on Ampersand.js model or collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ampersand.js

On my current project, I am using ampersand.js models and rest-collections. When I wire it to the api I am running into trouble. The api returns an object like this...

```json
{ 
    type: ...,
    multi: ...,
    data: <good stuff>
}
```

In order to load the data into the model or collection it is my understanding that I need to use parse.

After going over the docs it seems like I should place parse in the model.

In practice though, when I run fetch against the collection, it will not load the data into the models unless the parse property is on the collection. However, when I run a getOrFetch it will not load the data unless the parse property is on the model.

Nothing works if I put parse in both the model and the collection.

It really doesn't make sense that I should have to move it. I need to know where it is suppose to live, and what I need to do to get it to work.

Here are my model and collection:

```js
var Case = Model.extend({
    ajaxConfig: function () {
        return {
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': 'testing'
            }
        };
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    },
    props: {
        id: 'string',
        orgId: 'string',
        created: 'string',
        lastUpdated: 'string',

    }
});

var CaseCollection = RestCollection.extend({
    model: Case,
    url: '/cases',
    ajaxConfig: function () {
        return {
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': 'testing'
            }
        };
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        return response.data;
    },
    getCase: function (caseId, callbackfunc) {
        this.getOrFetch(caseId, function (err, model) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                callbackfunc(model.toJSON());
            }
        });
    },
    getCases: function (callbackfunc) {
        this.fetch({
            success: function (collection, response) {
                callbackfunc(collection.toJSON());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case, since your collection is doing fetching and not these models, it would go in the collection. Is it not working?

Comment: That is the problem. I have tried putting parse on the model, the collection, and both. I have currently been unsuccessful in finding a combo where I can run both fetch and getOrFetch and actually parse the response.

Comment: what's in the `data` property of the response, or what data structure it holds? is it an array of objects (matching a collection), or an object (matching a model)?

Comment: @Eliran When doing a fetch it is an array. When doing a getOrFetch it is an object.

Comment: you should than only override the collection's `parse`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on the data structure of the resource;

If the expected data is an array of objects, i.e. the client requests a **list**, you should override the collection's `parse`. If the resource responds with an object, i.e. the client requests a single **item**, you'd override the model's `parse`.

As per your case - the resource returns a list of objects, so override the collection's `parse` to traverse the response data and return the relevant value.

Provided that the objects in the response array are matching you model's structure, you should not override the model's `parse` as to not meddle with the model's construction.

Ampersand's `getOrFetch` should not be affected by this, as it's only caching existing data, or fetching the model from the expected resource.

The problem probably is in your server's (REST) API. Backbone derives the model's resource from the collection's `url`, by appending the model's `id` to the URL as another segment, so unless your backend doesn't serve anything at `/cases/{id}`, any fetch on a model tied to a collection will fail.

To solve this, either change the model's URL by overriding `rootUrl`, or create such a resource in the backend.

From the Backbone docs on `model.url`:

> Returns the relative URL where the model's resource would be located
>   on the server. If your models are located somewhere else, override
>   this method with the correct logic. Generates URLs of the form:
>   "[collection.url]/[id]" by default, but you may override by specifying
>   an explicit urlRoot if the model's collection shouldn't be taken into
>   account.